# ¿ Como hacer que funcione en segundo plano?

Tags: java, android

Tengo una App que muestra Toast indefinidamente, ¿ cómo hacer para que lo haga también en segundo plano aún sin estar utilizándola ?

Answer (score 1):

Un toast no puede crearse cuando esta en segundo plano (background) ya que necesita el contexto de la aplicación o actividad para que pueda ser creado.

**Una opción que realizaria sería crear una [notificacion](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) generada por un servicio en el cual el contexto es el mismo [servicio](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) ya que la clase [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) extiende de Context.**

#### ejemplo: como crear una notificación:

```
public static void creaNotificacion(long when, String notificationTitle,
                                      String notificationContent, String notificationUrl, Context ctx) {
    try {

        Intent notificationIntent;
        

        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        int smalIcon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

        /* Valida la url y crea un Intent */
        if (!"".equals(notificationUrl)) {
            notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(notificationUrl));
        } else {
            notificationIntent = new Intent();
        }

        /* Crea PendingIntent */
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        /* Construye la notificacion */
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                ctx).setWhen(when).setContentText(notificationContent)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle).setSmallIcon(smalIcon)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setTicker(notificationTitle)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify((int) when, notificationBuilder.build());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Notificacion", "createNotification::" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

y este es un ejemplo de como llamar el método para crear la notificación, sería la forma de realizarlo cuando un usuario ha seleccionado determinado comando, la notificación aparecera :

```
creaNotificacion(0,"Notificación Android!","Como llamar a una alerta o notificación para el usuario en la aplicación de Android?", "http://es.stackoverflow.com", getApplicationContext());
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Entiendo... pero no hay nada que se pueda crear que sea terriblemente molesto? Lo que necesito es que al iniciar la app aunque se salga de ella le salgan carteles (por eso decia del toast) o algo realmente molesto. Sencillamente para pararlo se cerraría la aplicación con el boton derecho y limpiar procesos. Pero no sé si me explico, que en segundo plano te salgan carteles o como toast.

Comment: He visto que realizan algo similar, por ejemplo una aplicación que no abres en días y cada cierto tiempo se muestra una notificación que invita a abrir la aplicacion nuevamente.

Comment: sabes como se llama o como puedo encontrarlo? A ver, mi objetivo, te lo voy a explicar bien, mi objetivo es que cuando pulse el boton, ya sea mediante toast, o mensajes, o bloqueando el proceso de whatsapp o quitando Internet , sea como sea, no puedas enviar un whatsapp a no ser que cierres el proceso de la App.

Comment: ¿sabrias como hacer eso?

Comment: Pero esto no tendría que ver con Whatsapp ya que no tienes acceso a  su control.

Comment: Pero y a Internet?

Answer (score -1):

Podrías utilizar un hilo, revisa esto tal vez puede servirte!
[AsyncTask: Tareas Asíncronas en Android](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/12/android-asynctask-hilos/)